# Minimum cardinality of lower-bounding subset of $[\omega]^\omega$

Tags: set-theory

Let $[\omega]^\omega$ denote the collection of all infinite subsets of $\omega$. Let us call  $S\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ *lower-bounding* if for all $a\in [\omega]^\omega$ there is $s\in S$ such that $s\subseteq a$.

What is the minimum cardinality that a lower-bounding subset of $[\omega]^\omega$ can have?

Comment: Please un-accept the incorrect answer and accept Ashutosh's correct answer instead.

Comment: OK I have done so

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They have size continuum, since there is an almost disjoint family of infinite sets of integers of size continuum.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  In more detail: If $\mathcal A$ is an almost disjoint family and if $S$ is lower-bounding, then each element of $\mathcal A$ must have a *different* subset in $S$ because of the almost-disjointness. So $|S|\geq|\mathcal A|$.